# Tensor Product of Homomophism of Arbitrary Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, tensor-products

Suppose we have four arbitrary vector spaces $V_1$,  $V_2$,  $V_3$, and  $V_4$.

Is it always the case that $Hom(H_1\otimes H_2,H_3\otimes H_4)=Hom(H_1,H_3)\otimes Hom(H_2,H_4)$?

This pretty easily follows in finite dimensions thanks to the algebraic formula for the Kronecker product. What about in infinite dimensions?

If the proof is technical, can anyone point to a textbook or paper discussing this?

Comment: No it's not true in general.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is in general false. Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-vector space. I use the notation $B(X  \times X)$ for the vector space of bilinear forms and $X^\prime$ for the algebraic dual space of $X$. Then
$$
 B(X \times X) = (X \otimes X)^\prime = \mathrm{Hom}(X \otimes X, \mathbb{K}) 
$$
and $$\mathrm{Hom}(X,\mathbb{K}) \otimes \mathrm{Hom}(X,\mathbb{K}) = X^\prime \otimes X^\prime \subsetneq B(X \times X).$$
Therefore $$\mathrm{Hom}(X,\mathbb{K}) \otimes \mathrm{Hom}(X,\mathbb{K})\subsetneq \mathrm{Hom}(X \otimes X, \mathbb{K}).$$
Showing that the statement is false in general with $H_1=H_2 = X$ and $H_3 = H_4 = \mathbb{K}$.